# How to get file path when I input a full filename in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I hope to get the path of a filename, just like get the result `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/` when I input the string `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo-2017-02-17-10-08-38_2271.JPG`

How can I do in javascript? Thanks!

Comment: try `var path = filename.match(/(.*)[\/\\]/)[1]||''; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var fullpath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo-2017-02-17-10-08-38_2271.JPG"
var pathWithoutFileName = fullpath.substr(0, fullpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo-2017-02-17-10-08-38_2271.JPG"
var path = x.substr(0,x.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fullpath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo-2017-02-17-10-08-38_2271.JPG"
var path = fullpath.substr(0, fullpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

The `+1` is to include the last forward slash.

Comment: replace your second line as fullpath.substr(0, fullpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar thanks for the observation. Had forgotten to alter the bogus variable names.